# Resize selection column width in WPF GridControl

Tags: wpf, gridview, grid, devexpress, gridcontrol

Could we resize the width of selection column in WPF `GridControl` (yellow area)?

[image: Resize selection column width in WPF GridControl]

Comment: http://prntscr.com/55wgaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [`Row Indicator Panel`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7288):
[image: Row Indicator Panel]
You can use [`TableView.IndicatorWidth`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTableView_IndicatorWidthtopic) property to resize its width.